# TYPO3 8.7 update with child elements m:n not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have an extension and a frontend form to create and update elements. The user can create an invoice with several dates which are stored as m:n records.

Creating an invoice and dates works with:

```
<f:form.checkbox name="newRechnungen[termine][]" value="{termin.uid}" />
```

But if I edit invoice and submit form, I get errors:

```
<f:form.checkbox name="rechnungen[termine][]" value="{termin.uid}" />
```

shows errror like:

> The form field "[items][][]" is invalid. Reason: "[]" used not as last argument, but somewhere in the middle (like foo[][bar])

changing the tag like described for solution to

```
<f:form.checkbox name="rechnungen[termine][{key}]" value="{termin.uid}" />
```

shows error:

> #1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "files": PHP Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in /usr/share/typo3/typo3_src-7.6.2/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/ObjectStorage.php line 155 =

The solution described on the documentation page with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for form tag is not working.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the generated HTML for the checkbox below has the correct format.

```
<f:form.checkbox name="rechnungen[termine][{key}]" value="{termin.uid}" />
```

You must have something like this in your HTML: `<input type="checkbox" name="tx_yourext_plugin[rechnungen][termine][1] value="__your value__" />`

The name like this `tx_yourext_plugin[rechnungen][termine][]` will not work.

By the error above I can say that your `{key}` variable is null. Try a `<f:debug>{key}</f:debug>` to check if it's null or not.

**UPDATE**

Add in your setter parameter `setTermine(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $temines = null)`

Comment: <input class="tocheck" id="check_162" name="tx_xxx_xxx[rechnungen][termine][1]" value="162" type="checkbox"> is html code in page and occures error. all checkboxes are submittet - also checkboxes which are not checked ... so I do not understand why they are submitted ... this is output in initialiceUpdateAction in controller:

Comment: Array
(
    [action] => update
    [controller] => Xxxxxx
    [rechnungen] => Array
        (
            [__identity] => 41
            [termine] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 136
                    [4] => 
                )

            )
)

Comment: the problem is, that typo3 is adding each checkbox a hidden field too with empty value. this causes the error

Comment: ahh, i remember that i had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it now by unset the empty values in initializeUpdateAction:

```
foreach($args['rechnungen']['termine'] as $key => $value) {
        if (intval($value) === 0) {
            unset($args['rechnungen']['termine'][$key]);
        }
    }
```